# Creating an array in ruby from excel spreadsheet (2 columns)

Tags: ruby, arrays

pretty simple issue but can't seem to figure it out. Checked for answers before coming here, nothing too informative yet.

Anyways, I have roughly 4000 rows in excel. Column A, and Column B.

What would be the best way to make an array and be able to store that?

Comment: http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following code,

```
require 'spreadsheet'
a=Array.new
b=Array.new
Spreadsheet.open('abc.xls') do |book|
  book.worksheet('Sheet1').each do |row|        
    a.push(row[0])
    b.push(row[1])
  end
end
```

This Will return two array a, b. Please check it

Comment: Thanks Shamith c. Well, it didn't fail or return an error, but when I run the ruby file in terminal, it doesn't 'do' anything, just starts a new $ line in the terminal. Is that what is suppose to happen? I mean using irb/rails c isn't going to accomplish anything here is it? B/c whatever you do in there is just...there? Unless you save it. Sorry for my noobness.

Comment: Alright I added book.write '/Users/davidpardy/caweek4/rubytests/newarrayfile2.txt' after the push and it is making the file in the rubytests folder (just did a .txt file for now) and there is all these symbols. For example  !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@AC˝ˇˇˇ I also added Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'

Comment: If you want to see array. Just add two line at end of the code  puts a    puts b

Comment: Hm, after adding push a and push b the array is showing up in terminal when I run it, but there are some duplications. For example, the first number in Column A, row 1 is -81.200399. This number shows up numerous times when the array is run in terminal. Also, the pattern through my excel sheet is a -81.xxxx for column A, and a 28.xxxx for column B. In terminal, there are many areas where there will be a bunch of 28.xxxx numbers in a row, and sometimes lots of -81.xxxx numbers in a row. Why would this be?